Balanced signal path or balanced in-/outputs
I'm planning to build a small device that can accompany my monitor controller in my home studio. The monitor controller is a TC Electronic Monitor Pilot, it has a volume knob and can select between 3 outputs. However, I'm missing the possibility to switch to mono, dim or mute the audio signal. Additionally the option to select between 2 sources.
The Monitor Pilot is designed with a remote control, so that the main box can be hidden away, and I want to do the same with my device using an Arduino Nano and an ATtiny84.
Building these options is not necessarily difficult, but since I'm working with balanced audio signals I'm in doubt what makes the most sense:

Create balanced input and output stages and make the desired features using controlled switches.
Ditch the input and output stages, double the number of switches and switch balanced signals all the way through.

Does it make sense to remove the complexity of the in-/output opamp stages? Is there a point in keeping the audio path balanced?
The device does not have to be state of the art quality, but since it's in my monitor path it has to be good. At the same time I don't want to spend a ton of money on components for a hobby project, like adding 20+ relays of $3-4 each which will quickly increase the build costs.
Will something like CD4066/74HC4066 be good for switching pro audio signals?
I'm not an expert in this field by any means, I have build some circuits in the past, but never anything of high quality. I have an education in electronics but I work in software development. So bear with me if I don't fully understand how everything works.

If the description of the "thing" is important, replace it with a block diagram and ditch the words. We use balanced signals when the signal is small or the noise/interference possibilities are high. Within a "thing" we tend to use signal ended signal processing.

Thanks @Andyaka, I could draw a block and place it in a picture of my studio, but I don't think that would help much in regards to answering whether or not it makes sense.
The question is not about the noise or interference but about the choice of circuit design.
I understand balanced in-/output stages has limitations (link) hence the question about if there's a point (benefit) in avoiding the conversion.

What is the voltage range of the audio signal? Usually balanced outputs are pretty strong so you would need +/-15V supplies, and that also rules out the 4066, you'd need a different switch IC for that voltage. Relays only need one supply for the coil and if you use DPDT relays, one relay can switch a balanced signal. So the switch ICs may seem simpler but once you factor in the cost and annoyance of extra power supplies...

That's a good point! I had not anticipated the audio signals to be that strong, and I guess that for the most sources it's not, but I don't want to saturate the components, I want as much headroom as possible.
The monitor controller which this device will sit in front off, accepts a max input level of +22 dBu, which, according to this image, is about +/- 12V.
In the end, I guess, it makes sense to use balanced in-/outputs stages and use relays.
